# How to know when an Amazon CloudFront distribution was created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a few CloudFront distributions and I need to know when each of them was created. The [Get Distribution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront/client/get_distribution.html) API only gives the last modified time but not the created time. Is there any way to know the creation time of an Amazon CloudFront distribution?

A workaround I thought was to use the Distribution metrics and get the first instance of a positive value for the requests (sum) metric but it would require additional IAM permissions and more API calls.

Comment: Why do you need creation time, just curious. The distribution metrics approach will not work as you can only go as far as 15 months

Comment: @NSS I need it for auditing purposes.

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to add a custom tag with a value of the current date when the distribution gets created. Of course, it will only be possible for new distribution.